# Custom Array Adapter

Tags: android, arrays, listview, adapter, custom-component

I'm writing a news-app and I'm having some trouble with displaying a custom list. All I want is that list items have 2 TextViews in them:

- News-Title and
- News-Description

These are contained in 2 static arrays: homeScreen.title[] and homeScreen.descriptionLong[].

Lower you have my code for the HashMap and the Adapter:

final static ArrayList> data = new ArrayList>();

```
static{
    HashMap<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i<HomeScreen.arrayLength; i++){
        row.put("Title", HomeScreen.title[i]);
        row.put("Description", HomeScreen.descriptionLong[i]);
        data.add(row);
    }
}

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
            data,
              R.layout.mainmenu,
              new String[] {"Title", "Description"},
              new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2});
   setListAdapter(adapter);
}

    public void onItemClick(SimpleAdapter arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            selectedNews = position;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is: " + selectedNews, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, ReadNews.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

The problem I'm having is that it only displays my 20'th (last) news information and also the default OnItemClick isn't working anymore. I'd appreciate your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the `row` instantiation inside the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<HomeScreen.arrayLength; i++){
    HashMap<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
    row.put("Title", HomeScreen.title[i]);
    row.put("Description", HomeScreen.descriptionLong[i]);
    data.add(row);
}
```

**Update:**

Your `OnItemClickListener` registration should look something like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                              int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was a great help. I've still got a problem. The default OnItemClick isn't working. I'll edit and add the code above.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for taking the time and helping noobs like me!